# show database stored (date)values as sellected in calender controle.

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have some stored date values in DB.
i want to show those dates as sellected in my calender control.i just need the code
(C# 2008 windows application) pls help me.

Comment: Please help us to help you and take a look at the [faq]

Comment: Or better, this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML Code :

```
<DatePicker Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,50,0,10" Name="dateText" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" >
        <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
            <Binding  Path="Date" />
        </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```

NOTE : You will have to bind the collection in the code-behind like following :

```
this.DataContext = data; // data will be the collection or list you are using.
```